# Как подключить mysql workbench к моему локальному контейнеру docker с sqlserver на нем?

Tags: mysql, docker

запустил образ mysql, забиндил порты, создаю новое подключение в MySql WorkBench, все ввел правильно, нажимаю Test Connection, **окно зависает, думает и потом ничего не происходит.**
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема может быть?

Comment: MySQL и SQLServer? Все верно?

Comment: какой вывод команды ```docker ps``` ? Какой вывод команды ```docker exec -ti CONTAINER_NAME mysql -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD $MYSQL_DATABASE -e 'show tables;' ```